# WebStorm. Run Jest in watch mode

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, enzyme, jestjs

I see that WebStorm supports **Jest** testing, and I see that I can toggle `auto-test` on code changes. But that's not the same as Jest `--watch` mode which is lot faster.

Is it possible to configure **watch** mode somehow?

[image]

**EDIT**
I found out that I can pass `--watch` option to each test config, but I would have to do it for every file, and also it's not possible to use `Jest` watch options like e.g. "filter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest `-watch` support will be provided in 2017.3. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26205

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the default Jest configuration and add --watch in Jest options. Every new configuration will contain this option.

By the way, could you please tell how you are going to use --watch in every configuration? As far as I know, this option usually is used for all tests in one config.

Moreover, please provide more details and documentation on filter option you mentioned.

Comment: sorry, can you help where to find the default configuration? thank you

Comment: See Templates section in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html